# Facebook feed dialog error: Parameter 'href' should represent a valid URL

Tags: angular, facebook, share

I get this error when pushing the button to share the url in facebook.

```
Parameter 'href' should represent a valid URL
```

the code i wrote for getting the link is

```
  fbShare(link?) {
    let fbFeedLink = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=' + environment.facebookAppId;
    if (link) {
      fbFeedLink = fbFeedLink + '&redirect_uri=' + link;
      fbFeedLink = fbFeedLink + '&link=' + link;
    } else {
      fbFeedLink = fbFeedLink + '&redirect_uri=' + environment.ownUrl;
      fbFeedLink = fbFeedLink + '&link=' + environment.ownUrl;
    }

    return fbFeedLink;
  }
```

the code in the html template that calls the link

```
<section id="tips" class="bg-white">
  <div class="container">
    <h3 [innerHTML]="'tips.title' | translate"></h3>
    <div class="tip-list">
      <div *ngFor="let tip of tips$; let i = index" class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 tip-title">Tip {{i+1}}</div>
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-11 col-sm-10 col-xs-8 tip first-tip">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">{{tip}}</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="txt-center">
                    <a class="my-fb-feed btn-social" target="_blank" [href]="helperService.fbShare()">
                      <span class="btn-svg btn-svg-share btn-svg-hover" [inlineSVG]="'assets/images/facebook-icon-black.svg'"></span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="inline txt-gray">Share</div>
                    <a class="btn-social" target="_blank" [href]="helperService.twShare()">
                      <span class="btn-svg btn-svg-share btn-svg-hover" [inlineSVG]="'assets/images/twitter-icon-black.svg'"></span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="inline txt-gray">Tweet</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

and the return link is

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=1166717177009473&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/challenges/en/the-power-of-energy-in-your-hands&link=http://localhost:4200/challenges/en/the-power-of-energy-in-your-hands
```

Here is the configuration in index.html

```
  <!-- Facebook SDK -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
  <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
  <script>
    !function (f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
      if (f.fbq) return; n = f.fbq = function () {
        n.callMethod ?
        n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
      };
      if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n; n.push = n; n.loaded = !0; n.version = '2.0';
      n.queue = []; t = b.createElement(e); t.async = !0;
      t.src = v; s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
    }(window, document, 'script',
      'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
    fbq('init', '1397361527189010');
    fbq('track', 'PageView-sharethelight');
  </script>
  <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1397361527189010&ev=PageView&noscript=1" /></noscript>
  <!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.vivapayments.com/web/checkout/js"></script>
```

Has someone any idea what it might be?
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post the code from the template? and the if you're using a script in index.html post it here

Comment: i posted the configuration in index.html but what do you mean by code from the template?

Comment: Facebook needs to be able to request the URL, to extract the OG meta data from the HTML code it returns. Obviously that won’t work for `localhost` URLs.